# EXCEL: How can you FORMAT a serial number into a MONTH ( Jan, Feb)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I extract the Month() number out of my date. I now want to change that number into a recognisable string Jan, Feb, Mar, etc. In Access you can use FORMAT, but what can we use in Excel?

E.g.

```
Date----------Formula---------Result-----What I want!
01/03/2010---Month(Date)--------3----------MAR
```

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **Format Cells** (right click on cell you want to format) -> Category:**Custom** and type:

> mmm

this is short month format

EDIT:

what I wrote would work on full date not on a single number, so if you do not need to go through all the steps (especially the =MONTH formula) this could be the answer

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. If you need the date and month next to each other, instead of =month(datecell) just make it =datecell and change the custom formatting as described in this answer.

Comment: I sued the simple =Datecell and then formatted "mmm" in custom formats. So simple I forgot to do it. It's had the added benefit of organising the dates as well when I add mmm-yy to the format! Bonus.

Answer (score 2):

You can format your date (in cell A1) to a text string using the formula:

```
=TEXT(A1, "mmm")
```

or you can leave it as a number but format it as a month:

```
Format Cells
  Category: Custom
    mmm
```

The month formats you can use are:

```
mmmm - Full month name
mmm - Abbreviated month name
mm - numeric month, zero padded
m - numeric month
```

Comment: The problem I see with this answer is that sorting by the month column will be alpha based instead of numerical. Therefore April will come before March, etc.

Comment: Comprehensive answer. Thank you for your time. I used the solution below, but yours is one that had helped me use TEXT (which I will come back to I'm sure)